# PHP - Preg match reversal?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do you inverse a Regex expression in PHP?

This is my code:

```
preg_match("!<div class=\"foo\">.*?</div>!is", $source, $matches);
```

This is checking the $source String for everything within the   Container and stores it in the $matches variable.

But what I want to do is reversing the expression i.e. I want to get everything that is NOT inside the  container. 
I know there is something called negative lookahead, but I am really bad with Regular expressions and didn't manage to come up with a working solution.

Simply using **?!**

```
preg_match("?!<div class=\"foo\">.*?</div>!is", $source, $matches);
```

Does not seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you give sample input output?

Comment: Sure, a sample input would be: _"Lorem ipsum <div class="foo"> I want to be excluded!</div> dolor sit"_ the output would be _"Lorem ipsum dolor sit"_

Comment: @Frank: Whatever you do, the output from regex function will not be continuous - you need to concatenate them together.

Comment: @tchrist: The other question doesn't quite apply. Actually, it has similar name but deal with different problem altogether.

Comment: @nhahtdh Ok, I was about to fix it but looks like that's been take care of.

Answer (score 1):

### New solution

Since your goal is to remove the matching divs, as mentioned in the comment, using the original regex with `preg_split`, plus `implode` would be the simpler solution:

```
implode('', preg_split('~<div class="foo">.*?</div>~is', $text))
```

[**Demo on ideone**](http://ideone.com/JNruj2)

### Old solution

I'm not sure whether this is a good idea, but here is my solution:

```
~(.*?)(?:<div class="foo">.*?</div>|$)~is
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/xF4hS7/4)

The result can be picked out from **capturing group 1** of each matches.

Note that the last match is always an empty string, and there can be empty string match between 2 matching divs or if the string starts with matching div. However, you need to concatenate them anyway, so it seems to be a non-issue.

The idea is to rely on the fact that lazy quantifier `.*?` will always try the sequel (whatever comes after it) first before advancing itself, resulting in something similar to *look-ahead assertion* that makes sure that whatever matched by `.*?` will not be inside `<div class="foo">.*?</div>`.

The div tag is matched along in each match in order to advance the cursor past the closing tag. `$` is used to match the text after the last matching div.

The `s` flag makes `.` matches any character, including line separators.

**Revision**: I had to change `.+?` to `.*?`, since `.+?` handle strings with 2 matching div next to each other and strings start with matching div.

---

Anyway, it's not a good idea to modify HTML with regular expression. [Use a parser instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: Okay thank you very much! This seems to be way more complicated than I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class=\"foo\">.*?</div>\K|.
```

You can simply do this by using `\K`.

> \K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

Comment: @nhahtdh yups not an ideal one.Will still leave it as of now